# Desglosar en binario una variable HEX

Tags: vb.net

Buenas a todos. Me surge un problema y no encuentro la formula para resolverlo.
Tengo un numero hexadecimal (8000) y esta compuesto por 16 bits que cada uno de ellos me dicen el estado de 16 cosas. Me gustaria separar esa variable para utilizar sus bits individualmente, ¿Cual seria la mejor manera de hacerlo?
 p.ej; 8000(HEX) = 1000000000000000(BIN)
Asi pues, necesitaria obtener 16 variables de tipo bool y trabajar con ellas independientemente...

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con los bits individuales de una variable lo mejor es utilizar "flags" que son constantes predefinidas en las que cada una tiene un bit activado y que al realizar una operación `And` con la variable indica si ese bit está activado.

Por ejemplo:

```
FLAG_PARAMETRO1 = 1      // en binario 0000000000000001
FLAG_PARAMETRO2 = 2      // en binario 0000000000000010
FLAG_PARAMETRO3 = 4      // en binario 0000000000000100
FLAG_PARAMETRO4 = 8      // en binario 0000000000001000   
...
```

Y así para las 16 variables que necesitas. Luego para saber si un bit está activado en la variable solo tienes que comparar con la bandera correspondiente:

```
If variable And FLAG_PARAMETRO4 = FLAG_PARAMETRO4 Then   
     // ese bit está en on
else
     // ese bit está en off
endif
```

o también puedes asignar el valor a una variable Boolean:

```
VarBool = (variable And FLAG_PARAMETRO4 = FLAG_PARAMETRO4)
```

Aunque no es estrictamente necesario, porque con los flags tienes bastante, pero eso al gusto de cada uno.

Otra utilidad importante del uso de flags es que se pueden comprobar varios bits al mismo tiempo utilizando el operador `Or`:

```
VarFlag = (FLAG_PARAMETRO1 Or FLAG_PARAMETRO3) Or FLAG_PARAMETRO7

VarBool = (variable And VarFlag = VarFlag)
```

Así puedes saber en una sola comparación si están activos varios bits.